# How to work with a Mac on a OpenSource project?

Tags: macos, open-source

I'm really interested in participating as a new developer in an OpenSource project. 
My Problem now is - what is the best way to participate with a Mac on an OSS Project? (Without using a Virtual Machine or DualBoot.)

As there is no usual apt-get system, what is the best way of working on such an existing project? Would you use Xcode or Eclipse or something else completely?

The setup for all those steps (Building, linking libraries etc.) has always been the part that never worked properly for me. Is there a tutorial which explains how to set the stuff up properly with these IDEs?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide more information about what problems you're having with building and linking?  Most UNIX source trees are configured, compiled, and installed correctly on both my MacBook Pro and my iMac by `./configure; make; sudo make install`.  If all of that works, the only additional tools you need to participate in open-source development are a text editor and a revision control system.

Comment: Generally, the problem was with the location of libraries.
They never were quite where the build system expected them and led to countless errors when building. (And I'd like to prevent cluttering of my system with libraries placed everywhere...)
What I'd really like is a way to setup the library paths in an IDE like XCode once, and let it take care afterwards.
Is this realistic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) is a package system for Mac, it gives you most of what apt-get does on a Linux system.

Comment: Yes MacPorts is very similar. I've tried both and stuck with Fink, but YMMV.

Comment: I tried it with fink and it is really quite neat and works without cluttering my system. Usually, it requires additional flags for configuring, but I managed it so far. Great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a very simple recipe.

1. Pick a Java open source project.
2. Install Eclipse on MacOS.
3. Go to work.

No libraries, no linking, no fuss, no muss, no bother.

If you want to work in C or C++, the question is going to be whether you are the only person. For a project that has already been ported to mac, you just do what the others are doing. You run 'configure', and all is well, and you use and editor to edit and gdb to debug.

Comment: Agreed, that is a very comfortable way.
But as many interesting projects are written in C or C++ with the pretty building system, I'd like to know how to do it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is the best choice, I think, irrespective of project